# jQuery how to achieve a toggleClick functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div section that would hide/show based on clicking a button.
And I'm using this jQuery code to show/hide divs based on clicking the "pop-design1", "pop-design2", "pop-design3" buttons.

When the 'pop-design1' button is clicked once it shows the div. Now what I want to achieve is that when it is clicked again it does the opposite of the script.

I think jQuery had a function toggleClick once that could achieve something like this but it is deprecated now.

Thanks for your time

Thanks

Comment: added live link to help make it clearer. thanks for any help

Comment: Use native javascript. It's easy to implement it. Just set an attribute with a counter . Use a condition to check whether the counter is set or not ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `removeClass()` or `addClass()`, use `toggleClass()` and instead of `css('display',...)` use `.toggle()`

```
$('.pop-design1').click(function(){
    $(".design-preview li:not(.design-preview2).selected").removeClass('selected');
    $(".design-list li:not(.design-list2).selected").removeClass('selected');
    $(".design-preview2").toggleClass('selected');
    $(".design-list2").toggleClass('selected');
    $(".overlay").toggle();
});
```

Comment: i tried this but it messes up with different content divs showing on top of each other. To give you an idea of it, this is the live page using your code:

http://www.expertfrontend.com/test/2.html

Comment: this is pretty good. just one thing. When the plus sign is clicked the circle changes its background, size, and the plus turns into a minus. when clicked the second time it should go back to its current state. Right now it tends to keep its 'minus bigger size different background color' state inspite of it.

Live link for your new code: http://www.expertfrontend.com/test/2.html

Comment: Ahh. The current code is too complicated. Updated once more. Check it.